# Problems when sharing internet over wifi and magic mouse/keyboard

Tags: wifi, bluetooth, internet-sharing

When I enable internet sharing over Wi-Fi, all my Bluetooth devices (mouse, keyboard, headset) can not be used any longer, they partly disconnect or just not respond from my input. And my iPhone can connect though but has not really internet.

To enable internet sharing I followed the official guide from here: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25327?locale=en_US

I'm using channel 11, WPA-2 and I'm sure it is the correct LAN I selected.

EDIT:

Tested channel 40 and this seems to be better but my iPhone still has no internet access.

Comment: Is it only with Internet sharing or does it happen when you enable and connect to WiFi networks as well?

Comment: No, only with internet sharing... It's a really strange behaviour

Comment: @Allan sorry, forgot to mention you